# application/window switcher on xubuntu/xfce: group windows by application

Tags: xfce, xubuntu, alt-tab

I'coming from a mac, where the alt-tab application switcher is grouping windows of the same application as one entry in the application switcher dialog - I'm used to this behaviour, having ALL windows in the list is just too much.

Is this possible with the default xfce alt-tab application switcher, or is there an (lightweight) alternative?

Comment: still interested if there is an easy solution to this problem. though, it's not as urgent anymore, using `jumpapp` now, what a great tool.

Answer (score 2):

Well, technically, there is a solution, although I'm not sure you'll like it:

Set the shortcut for **Window Manager** -> **Keyboard** -> **Switch window for same application** from the default Super + Tab to Alt + Tab.

This won't come with the regular nice visual window list of the normal window switching command though, and also behaves differently in that it instantly switches on key press, instead of allowing you to choose from a list, or abort it with Esc.

Comment: this is not what I'm trying to achieve? the list from "alt-tab" should be reduced to one entry per application, that's all...your's is a solution for cycling windows of the same app, right?

Comment: Yes. It seems I misunderstood the question. Should it always switch to the last-accessed window of a single application?

Answer (score 0):

(an imperfect solution) To reduce the number of windows in the list, go to Window Manager Tweaks > Cycling > uncheck "Cycle through windows on all workspaces". Then put each application on its own workspace.

Ctrl-F1, etc switches workspaces, then Alt-Tab cycles application windows.

Comment: uugh. Since a short time, I'm using one workspace for each of my projects I am working on, so your workaround is not an option. Funny thing is: My new workflow is also a workaround for my problem, as I normaly have one IDE, one terminal and one browser window open - on each workspace. But, further on, I am also using `jumpapp` now (far better than alt-tab, in most of the cases, at least for me), so cycling is rarely used anymore...